# UDP Server android application wont upload to phone

Tags: java, android, udp

I have built a upd server listen code to upload on my phone and listen to data packets. This code will compile but for some reason it wont load to my phone. I don't see any errors anywhere. Why could this be ? this is my whole Mainactivity code :

```
package roman10.tutorial.udpcommserver;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class UdpServer extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private TextView textView; 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    runUdpServer();
}
private static final int UDP_SERVER_PORT = 4000;
private static final int MAX_UDP_DATAGRAM_LEN = 1500;
private static final String ipAdd = new String("172.30.42.80");

private void runUdpServer() {
    String lText;

//      byte[] lMsg = new byte[MAX_UDP_DATAGRAM_LEN];
//      DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(lMsg, lMsg.length);
//      DatagramSocket ds = null;
        byte buffer[] = new byte[MAX_UDP_DATAGRAM_LEN];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        try {
//          ds = new DatagramSocket(UDP_SERVER_PORT);
//          //disable timeout for testing
//          //ds.setSoTimeout(100000);
//          ds.receive(dp);
            //lText = new String(lMsg, 0, dp.getLength());
//          Log.i("UDP packet received", lText);
//          textView.setText(lText);
            DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
            InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(ipAdd, UDP_SERVER_PORT);
            s.bind(address);

        lText = new String(buffer,0,packet.getLength());
        Log.i("UDP packet received", lText);
        textView.setText(lText);

        System.out.println("Waiting...");
        s.receive(packet);
        if (s != null) {
            s.close();
        }
//          s.close();
            System.out.println("Received!");
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.print("we are done ");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1)
You are not returning from your onCreate (until you have received something). The activity can't continue to start (certainly not call onStart, onResume etc.

2)
Then you are doing I/O on the main thread, network I/O even, not recommended and usually detected as not allowed on android and force closed. You will get a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Fortunately both those issues can be solved by creating a separate thread and executing `runUdpServer()` there. 
Short example, instead of:

```
runUdpServer();
```

do:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    runUdpServer();
  }
};
thread.start();
```